# How do you know whether this graph is 3-colorable or not?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

[image: Graph with proper 5 coloring]

How do you know that this graph is or is not 3-colorable? If it is not, I don't understand how I would prove that either. I was told the chromatic number is 4 but I am still unsure on how to prove that.

Comment: if you know  chromatic number is 4, then by definition it is not 3-colorable.

Comment: But how do I prove the chromatic number is 4. I can just give it a 4 coloring and see it holds. I'm still stuck.

Comment: @CalvinLin sorry, I thought its edge coloring.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. That phrasing was a mistake on my part. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a diagram of the graph with the vertices labeled and an edge list.

```
    A
B C D E F
G H I J K

     edges: AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,BH,BK,CG,CI,DH,DJ,EI,EK,FG,FJ
more edges: GH,HI,IJ,JK,KG
```

It has no valid 3-colorings:

`GHIJK` is a 5-cycle. It costs us at least three colors to color it.

Suppose without loss of generality that `I` has the least common coloring, which is $3$

This means that `H` and `J` must have colors $2$ and $1$ respectively, without loss of generality.

And thus `G` and `K` have colors $1$ and $2$ respectively.

This means that `C` has color $2$, `D` has color $3$ and `E` has color $1$.

This means that `A` must have a fourth color.

Thus the graph is not $3$-colorable:

Comment: Do you mean G and K should have 2 and 1?

Comment: @slowmo Yes. I mixed up the colors of `H` and `J` according to the drawing by my chair.

Comment: Also, how do you know a 5-cycle needs 3 colors?

Comment: If you tried to $2$-color it, you'd start at an arbitrary point and alternate colors ... and end up with the 1st node and the 5th node having the same color. This is the only strategy that could work for $2$-coloring a cycle and it fails so we need at least $3$ colors.

Comment: Nice argument! To put it more elegantly (IMHO, YMMV): Assume the whole graph  is properly colored with $3$ colors. Since the subgraph $H$ induced by the bottom-row vertices is $3$-chromatic, for each color $i$ there must be a vertex $x_i$ in $H$ of color $i$ which has neighbors in $H$ of all other colors; else we could get a proper $2$-coloring of $H$ by recoloring the vertices of color $i$.  Let $y_i$ be the middle-row vertex above $x_i$ in the figure. Since $y_i$ is joined to all the bottom-row neighbors of $x_i$, $y_i$ must also have color $i$. But this leaves no color for the top vertex.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a proper vertex coloring of the graph. The top vertex has some color, call it "red". There are no red vertices in the middle row. There may be some red vertices in the bottom row; however, if each red vertex in the bottom row is recolored to have the same color as the vertex directly above it in the middle row, the new coloring will still be proper. Thus, the bottom row can be properly colored with one less color than the whole graph. Since the bottom row is an odd cycle, its chromatic number is $3$, so the chromatic number of the whole graph is at least $4$.

This is the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph), the smallest triangle-free graph of chromatic number $4$; it's the [Mycielskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) of the cycle graph $C_5$.

Comment: I don't see how that recolouring is allowed. If the second row is GGBBB and the bottom row RYRGY, then Reds on the bottom row are adjacent to Blue, Green and Yellow, so cannot be recoloured to any other colour.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis In your example the bottom row would be recoloured GYBGY which is a proper colouring **of the bottom row** (induced subgraph), not the whole original graph. The graph in this question (called the Grötzsch graph) is the [Mycielskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) of the cycle graph $C_5$.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks!